# Оптимизация в visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Как включить опцию оптимизации кода компилируемой программы?

Comment: Используйте Release сборку

Comment: @dIm0n, не обязательно.

Answer (score 3):

Проект -> Свойства и одно из двух (больше похоже что второе):

[image: скриншот настроек]

[image: скриншот оптимизации]

Comment: Так второе стоит по умолчанию в Release сборке. А первое это LinkTimeOptimization в других компиляторах. VS, конечно, давно не пользовался, но вроде бы так

Comment: Вообще в vs больше опций оптимизации. На послднем скрине например. Тот-же /GL

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков, вполне возможно, но я ни разу не настраивал.